# FEDEX Web Service create open Shipment

Tags: fedex

When I use fedex webService to create an open shipment, I want my recipient address to be changed only by the account and password I use, which parameter should I use?

Comment: Please share more details. Is this even related to programming? Why not ask Fedex itself if you are facing any problem with their APIs?

Comment: I don't know how to contact the official fedex developers. My problem is that in the fedex Web Services Open Shipping api setting the parameter that prohibits modifying the shipping address, I now need to know which parameter is this parameter